# Can't copy files from NTFS to macOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bash, ntfs, ntfs-3g

So, recently, my computer ran into a problem, and I decided to reset it, but before that, I need to back up onto a hard drive.

However, the only hard drive I can find that has the free space available is an NTFS hard drive, with some data on it.

As everyone knows, macOS can only read NTFS hard drives, and so if I want to use time machine to back up, I need to erase that data and change it to APFS/HFS+/exFAT first. I don't want to lose my 1.* GB sized audio downloads that I paid for, and so I'm copying the files on the NTFS hard drive to my desktop.

However, another problem approaches.

While midway copying a file called `The Very Hungry Caterpillar.mp3`, apple says:
[image: Oh noes...]

Hmm..., I thought, There was a similar error that I encountered previously with an `flv` file, and I fixed it by going into the command line and cp-ing it to my desktop. This should work again.

Or so I thought.

```bsh
$ cp /Volumes/New\ Volume/Top\ 50绘本的pdf及mp3音频/38\ The\ Very\ Hungry\ Caterpillar/The\ Very\ Hungry\ Caterpillar.mp3 /Users/Aaron/Desktop/Top\ 50绘本的pdf及mp3音频/38\ The\ Very\ Hungry\ Caterpillar 
cp: /Volumes/New Volume/Top 50绘本的pdf及mp3音频/38 The Very Hungry Caterpillar/The Very Hungry Caterpillar.mp3: Input/output error
```

The copying stopped at 22 MB of a 30.* MB file.

I thought again. Maybe I used NTFS-3G to mount it. What about that?

What a nuisance.

```bsh
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/NTFS -olocal -oallow_other
$ cd /Volumes/NTFS/Top\ 50绘本的pdf及mp3音频 
$ cd 38\ The\ Very\ Hungry\ Caterpillar/
$ cp The\ Very\ Hungry\ Caterpillar.mp3 /Users/Aaron/Desktop/Top\ 50绘本的pdf及mp3音频/38\ The\ Very\ Hungry\ Caterpillar 
cp: The Very Hungry Caterpillar.mp3: Device not configured
cp: The Very Hungry Caterpillar.mp3: could not copy extended attributes to /Users/Aaron/Desktop/Top 50绘本的pdf及mp3音频/38 The Very Hungry Caterpillar/The Very Hungry Caterpillar.mp3: Device not configured
```

Oh, and finder froze too.

Now, the Questions:

1. Most importantly, how to copy a file from that NTFS drive to my desktop?
2. Why would cp return I/O error when copying after mounted by the macOS default?
3. The OSXFUSE NTFS-3G volume is still there. Why would cp return "Device not configured" ?

Comment: Error -36 is an i/o error, commonly a damaged sector on the disk you are reading from. It ought to have no connection to Fuse/3G as they're not needed for reading. Potentially, the file path could cause the issue, so you could try renaming the path to be 'ascii'. Otherwise, check the drive on a Windows machine.

Comment: I'm worried about the risk of losing some or all of your data. You're having trouble copying from the drive now, but if anything goes wrong later, when *everything* is on that drive... It's all be gone. Remember: when you erase your primary copy, your "backup" isn't a backup anymore, it's the new primary copy, and you no longer have a backup (unless you made *another* backup).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Your wording is confusing. Can you please reword it to make it more understandable?

Comment: @Aaron To summarize: your plan has several opportunities for catastrophic data loss. I suggest you rethink your plan.